# jQuery background color animation on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-color

This is probably blatantly simple and easy to fix (or impossible) but I've been trying to implement my hover effect on page load.

I have a navigation system with div boxes, and the following jQuery to animate it's background color on hover:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();  
/* Menu buttons fade */
      $jq(document).ready(function() {
                $jq("#box").hover(function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF9933"}, 400);
                },function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
                });

      $jq("#box2").hover(function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#9DE263"}, 400);
                },function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
                });

      $jq("#box3").hover(function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#0099FF"}, 400);
                },function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
                });

      $jq("#box4").hover(function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#8B0099"}, 400);
                },function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
                });

      $jq("#box5").hover(function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#336666"}, 400);
                },function() {
                $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
                });
      });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do however, is duplicate the same effect, however instead it occurs when the page loads - with one animating just after the other. A good example is [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) - the navigation bar buttons color animate one after the other.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

mlazim14

Comment: That is some copy paste happy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what your looking for:

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["", "#FF9933", "#9DE263", "#0099FF", "#8B0099", "#336666"];

    $jq("[id^='box']").hover(function() {
       $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: colors[this.id.replace('box','')]}, 400);
    },function() {
       $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, 400);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qwp49/)

Note that color animations like these require jQuery UI or preferably just the much smaller color animation script.

EDIT: to make the boxes animate on load, do something like this:

```
$jq("[id^='box']").each(function() {
      $jq(this).stop().delay(time).animate({ backgroundColor: colors[this.id.replace('box','')]}, speed, function() {
          $jq(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "navy" }, speed);
      });
      time=time+(speed*2);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qwp49/1/)

Comment: Thanks for making my code a little more semantic! However, that hasn't solved my original problem of making the background color animate when the page loads, each box in order just after the other. Again, if you'd like an example of what I mean - the CSS Tricks site I linked to in my first post is a good example of what I'm looking for.

Comment: @mlazim14 - updated my answer, not really sure what your looking for, but I'm guessing it something similar to that ?